# Thousands of concurrent packets, ThreadPool vs BeginRead?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, threadpool, udpclient

I'm running an application that has 5000 instances of the [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) class since I need to transmit packets concurrently on different ports.

I'm currently using a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), which runs on the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx). It has a very short `Interval` with many `Elapsed` events firing.

Would it be better to modify the application to work using `BeginRead`/`EndRead` functions of the [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx)?

Comment: What are you using your Timer for exactly ? I don't get it, could you please add more details about this.

Comment: If you're using *a* timer, and not several times, then there is only one thread pool thread being used, not several.  That said, the begin/end read functions are designed for doing this, and won't take up any thread's time while it's doing the async work.  So, either solution *could* be done properly, and with minimal overhead.  Of course, either solution could be implemented improperly and consume way more resources than is acceptable.

Comment: @darkey Every time the `timer.elapsed` event is fired the script checks for few conditions, and if the conditions passes it send and then receive, using `UdpClient.Send` and `UdpClient.Receive`, every `Timer.Elapsed` event could have any number of udp messages, 0 or 1 or more depending on checked conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with IO operations (i.e, network, file system, etc.), you should always use async operations, i.e BeginXXX/EndXXX, XXXAsync/XXXCompleted, XXXAsync in context of async/await. These operations use so known [IO complition ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In two words, it doesn't consume any CPU resources while the data is transmitting. As soon as the requested data is loaded, it takes a thread from the ThreadPool and queues the handler to this thread. In your case, you are wasting CPU resources. Instead of doing some useful work, the threads just wait until the data is transmitted. Also, the ThreadPool has limited number of threads (usually equal to number of CPU cores). So, in you case it sends/receives data only to/from 2 clients in a time.

The asynchronous methods might seem very complicated (especially BeginXXX/EndXXX), but there are a lot of wrappers which significantly simplifies thier useage. For example, you can use [Rx's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) [FromAsyncPattern](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc10) extension method, or you can use new [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) asyncronous model.

Comment: +1, proper way to do it if you want proper performance is to make sure you use the IO in async mode, so that cpu isn't used until data is there.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, my only concern now is the decreased readability of the code by using async (BeginXXX/EndXXX), at the moment, I have 1 function, its signature is: `byte[] SendReceive(IPEndPoint ipe, byte[] senddata)`.

Comment: Like I said, just use either async/await or Rx. The readability will be much better, especially with async/await.